# Click Once release channels and roll out features?

Tags: .net-framework, deployment, clickonce

We're currently using ClickOnce to deploy our Windows Form application. We're investigating the possibilities to use multiple release channels, such as Stable and Beta and the possibility to only release an update to x-number of clients.

I can't find any information indicating the ClickOnce have support for this out of the box and I'm wondering if anyone have solved this with a workaround?

Comment: You should read this question over at Stackoverflow pretty much answers this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478991/vs2012-sync-project-properties-and-clickonce-build-number

Comment: @Ramhound, that link has nothing to do with creating multiple release channels.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you want, but it's close.  It might be useful for others who look for this.

Applications only check for updates from one location, regardless of install location.  I'm going to start calling this the "stable" directory.

I'm going to make another directory for beta installation.

When a beta version live test is acceptable, I'll just copy that version over to the stable directory, and all clients with a lesser version of that will update.

Users would never automatically update to a beta version, which may be a downside of this approach.  To run a beta requires an installation from a beta link.  And those beta user will eventually just be running the stable version unless they continually opt-in for each beta release.

Comment: I'm investigating this since I'm migrating a project from the old VS Setup Project deployment over to ClickOnce. Since we can specify a web URL to check for updates, then can we just create two directories (stable, beta) like you say? Could any given app deployment switch between the channels?